# Jquery Submit Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, submit

I can't seem to make this to work. I'm trying to submit form using jquery dialog and I want to receive in php so I can use $_POST.

Any idea?

HTML:

```
<div id="table_rows_form">
    <form id="fieldsform" action="system/create">
        <label for="fields">How many fields are needed?</label>
        <input type="text" id="fields" name="fields" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_rows').on('click', function() {
        $('#table_rows_form').dialog({
            open: function() {
                $(this).find('[type=submit]').hide();
            },
            draggable: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            width: 'auto',
            minHeight: 235,
            title: 'Number of Fields',
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            buttons: {
                "Send": function() {
                    $('#fieldsform').submit(function(event) {
                        var formData = {
                            'fields': $('input[name=fields]').val()
                        };
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: $('#fieldsform').attr('action'),
                            data: formData,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            encode: true
                        });
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

The dialog opens correctly but when pressing send button doesn't do anything and doesn't gives any error at the console. Any idea about the error? I'm a newbie with jquery.

Comment: `$('#fieldsform').submit(function(event) {` adds `submit` event handler to `#fieldsform`. Maybe you should remove this line (and related `});`

Comment: try using   event.preventdefault() inside  fieldsform submit

Comment: @Sumeet I've tried and doesn't changes anything

Comment: @Regent didn't get your idea. removing ajax and using only submit()? It doesn't use $_POST, it builds the url with data. I've tried. Gives me something like tables/create?fields=4 and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just adding a submit handler with your code `$('#fieldsform').submit( ... )` so it doesn't trigger anything.

Rather, you should do that on document ready, and in the click handler for "Send" button, call `$('#fieldsform').submit();`

Comment: So you're saying to build $('#fieldsform').submit(...) outside the dialog an then call it at button: "Send": $('#fieldsform').submit(); right?

Comment: @user3718566 yes. And don't forget to add `return false` at the end of submit handler function to prevent default `form` behaviour (if you of course want to prevent it).

Comment: Yes. If you put it inside the "Send" callback function, it will keep attaching a new "submit" handler to the form everytime "Send" is clicked. It's a little confusing: `.submit()` will submit, while `.submit(callback_function)` is only attaching the handler.

Comment: I've tried and still doesn't work. Any other idea? It evens doesn't gives me any error at the console.

Comment: First time using jsfiddle. Can't seem to make it run at there.
http://jsfiddle.net/gn5m1wsn/

Comment: Thanks now it submits but I think I'm missing something, on submit shouldn't it read the action url and redirect to it? If we use submit() shouldn't it read action and post to that url redirecting to the page?

Comment: @user3718566 using `return false` in `submit` function we prevent default browser `submit` behaviour and do all things manually (send request manually, parse result manually). If you want to redirect to another page, you can do it manually in ajax `success` function too. Take a look at [$.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for full information. And on more thing: if you write to someone in comments, use '@ username' (without space) to notify user about your comment. Otherwise, most probably user will not ever read it.